# sum different columns in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very big data.frame and want to sum the values in every column.

So I used the following code:

```
sum(production[,4],na.rm=TRUE)
```

or

```
sum(production$X1961,na.rm=TRUE)
```

The problem is  that the data.frame is very big. And I only want to sum 40 certain columns with different names of my data.frame. And I don't want to list every single column. Is there a smarter solution?

At the end I also want to store the sum of every column in a new data.frame.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
colSums(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

where `sapply(df, is.numeric)` is used to detect all the columns that are numeric.

If you just want to sum a few columns, then do:

```
colSums(df[c("X1961", "X1962", "X1999")], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: This answer is better than the currently accepted answer because it makes explicit what is being summed (columns or rows) by using `colsums`. The other answer requires that the user know that `sum` works by column by default.

Answer (score 4):

```
res <- unlist(lapply(production, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sum(x, na.rm=T)))
```

will return the sum of each numeric column.

You could create a new data frame based on the result with

```
data.frame(t(res))
```

Comment: I know. But the problem is that there are also 40 comuns which are not numeric.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to include every single column, you somehow have to indicate which ones to include (or alternatively, which to exclude)

```
colsInclude <- c("X1961", "X1962", "X1963") # by name
    # or # 
colsInclude <- paste0("X", 1961:2003)  # by name
    # or # 
colsInclude <- c(10:19, 23, 55, 147)   # by column number
```

To put those columns in a new data frame simply use `[ ]` as you've done:    '

```
newDF <- oldDF[, colsInclude]
```

To sum up each column, simply use colSums

```
sums <- colSums(newDF, na.rm=T)
    # or # 
sums <- colSums(oldDF[, colsInclude], na.rm=T)
```

Note that `sums` will be a vector, not necessarilly a data frame. 
You can make it into a data frame using `as.data.frame`

```
sums <- as.data.frame(sums)
    # or, to include the data frame from which it came #
sums <- rbind(newDF, "totals"=sums)
```